# How to navigate through a ListView in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have an activity, which contains of a Fragment (ListView). This ListView represents a file structur (DMS or File Explorer). When i click on a list item the list is updated (adapter.notifyDataSetChanged) and so on. But how can i navigate back to the previouse list representation?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking of a file system as a tree may help visualize the solution.  Every node of a tree (outside of the root) has parent references as well as children references (assuming the node is not a leaf).  If you are already traversing this tree downwards, you probably have some form of child reference for each element of the file system since when you click an item, you say your list updates itself with the elements that are within the directory you selected.  If this is the case, I would also add a reference to the parent directory you came from and link it to a back button of sorts.  Assuming the parent reference is unique, i.e. directory level x and level y have different identifiers, then there should be no problem.

You can also look to implement a counter of sorts that increments as you traverse the tree downwards and decrements when climbing back up - this can become useful if two levels of your file system have the same identifier.  Without code it may be difficult to advise on specific implementation practices, however the main idea remains the same: you need to hold references both ways (parent and children references) for each element within the system - when possible.

NOTE: if you store 'null' (or some specific value you can check for) parent references for root element(s) of the system, or 'null' child references for leaves, you will know when you cannot ascend or descend further.  This may allow you to send a Toast on screen to notify the user their action was invalid or even removing the back button when you have reached the top.

I hope this helps, best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On last question: My listview is in a fragment. How can i commit the changes to the main activity (because the backButton method is not available in fragments) ?

Comment: Personally, I had imagined a button embedded in the fragment that would act as a back button (not necessarily the ancestral navigation back button in the action bar) - you can easily make this happen with a LinearLayout, and you can hide this view when you've reached the top level of the structure. When this button is clicked you can perform the logic to find the parent reference and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` with the correct contents.